# Db2 on IBM Cloud: How to get the table space?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I use DB2 on IBM Cloud. I got a message:

> Unable to allocate new pages in table space "XXXXX"

May I know what's the table space for free plan and Flex plan? How to expand the space?

Comment: Are you using Db2 on Cloud or Db2 Warehouse on Cloud? How much of your allocated space is used? You can see that in the dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Db2 on Cloud's free plan, your tablespace would be `<username>space1`.

For the free version you are limited to that one tablespace and cannot increase it yourself.

Flex is a different story where you can increase it through a management page.